# How to refresh _loginPartial.cshtml after AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, partial-views

i'm working on a simple asp.net web app right now and I've hit a bit of a roadblock in the form of my _loginPartial.cshtml not reloading after an async login.

I've changed the basic login to use a modal and login async, toasting a success message where appropriate. The problem is that the page has to refresh before the if (Request.Authenticated) block is hit again to show the logged in users name instead of the 'login' button.

My question - is there a line of javascript I can use in my ajax success block to refresh the _loginPartial.cshtml without reloading the whole page?

Here is my _loginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnShowLogin").click(function () {
            if (($('#RegisterModal').hasClass('in')))
                $('#RegisterModal').modal('hide');

            $('#LoginModal').modal('show');
        });

        $('#btnShowRegister').click(function () {
            if (($('#LoginModal').hasClass('in')))
                $('#LoginModal').modal('hide');

            $('#RegisterModal').modal('show');
        })
    })

    $(document).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 27) {
            $('#LoginModal').modal('hide');
        }
    });
</script>

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <a class="btn btn-green" href="#" id="btnShowRegister">
            Sign Up
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus "></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-green" href="#" id="btnShowLogin">
            Log In
            <i class="fa fa-sign-in "></i>
        </a>

    </ul>

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml", new VaceProject.Models.LoginViewModel())
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Account/Register.cshtml", new VaceProject.Models.RegisterViewModel())
}
```

And here is my Login.cshtml

```
@using VaceProject.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<script>
    //form submit event
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#login-form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Create formData object with antiforgeryToken
            var formData = new FormData($('#login-form')[0]);
            formData.append('Email', $('#emailTxt').val());

            //validate empty fields
            var isValid = IsModelValidated(formData);

            if (isValid) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Login","Account")",
                    data: formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data == "Success") { //toastr popup 
                            toastr.success("Logged in.");
                            $('#LoginModal').modal('hide');

                        }
                        else if (data == "Failure")
                            toastr.error("Login failed. Check your credentials and try again.");
                        else if (data == "Locked out")
                            toastr.info("Login failed because this account is locked out. Please contact an admin for help.");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status) {
                        toastr.error("Something went wrong.");

                    }

                });
            }
        })
    })

</script>
<div class="modal fade container" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content col-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="login-form" role="form">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5>Login using your VACE Edu account details or click <a href="#">here</a> to register your interest in a personalised communication program.</h5>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="fieldlist">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })

                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "emailTxt" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })

                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="margin-left-33">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="form-group pull-right padding-10">

                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info cancel-btn" />

                    </div>
                </div>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                </p>*@
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

aaand my Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - VACE Education</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/toastr.min.js?v=1"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <link href="~/Content/toastr.min.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("VACE EDU", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>

                    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Students", "Index", "Student")</li>
                    }

                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Courses", "Index", "Course")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Instructors", "Index", "Instructor")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Departments", "Index", "Department")</li>
                </ul>
                <div id="loginPartial">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - VACE Education</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
<script>
    //Validates form fields against empty 
    function IsModelValidated(formData) {
        debugger;
        var errorMessage = '';
        for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(key, value);

            switch (key) {
                case "ForeName":
                    if (value == '')
                        errorMessage += '<li>Please enter forename.</li>';

                    break;
                case "LastName":
                    if (value == '')
                        errorMessage += '<li>Please enter surname.</li>';
                    break;
                case "Email":
                    if (value == '')
                        errorMessage += '<li>Please enter a valid email address.</li>';
                case "DOB":
                    if (value == '')
                        errorMessage += '<li>Please select a valid date of birth.</li>';

                default:
            }
        }

        if (errorMessage !== '') {
            toastr.error(errorMessage);
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
</script>
```

Finally, my login method

```
   //
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ApplicationUser signedInUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
        ViewBag.IsAdmin = isAdminUser(signedInUser);

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(signedInUser.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return Json("Success");
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return Json("Locked out");
            //case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            //    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Json("Failure");
        }
    }

    return Json("Success"); 
}
```

Right now all that's happening is the toast appears 'Login successful' but the _loginPartial is not refreshing to show the logged in users name until the page is refreshed.

Hopefully I've described my problem clearly enough, I look forward to reading any responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new controller or utilize existing controller which returns `_LoginPartial` partial view like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult RefreshLoginPartial()
{
    // do something

    return PartialView("_LoginPartial");
}
```

And then use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to refresh `div` element containing partial view you want to replace inside `data == "Success"` condition, as provided in example below:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "@Url.Action("Login","Account")",
     data: formData,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     success: function (data) {
        if (data == "Success") { //toastr popup 
            toastr.success("Logged in.");
            $('#LoginModal').modal('hide');

            // refresh login partial view from AJAX
            // $.get is shorthand form of AJAX GET request, see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
            $.get('@Url.Action("RefreshLoginPartial", "ControllerName")', function (result) {
                $('#loginPartial').html(result);
            });
        }
        else if (data == "Failure")
            toastr.error("Login failed. Check your credentials and try again.");
        else if (data == "Locked out")
            toastr.info("Login failed because this account is locked out. Please contact an admin for help.");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            toastr.error("Something went wrong.");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="loginPartial">
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

Refresh the whole partial view through ajax, using your wrapping div replace its contents.

This [link might help you](https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/)

Comment: Thanks sir. So after reading the link my best bet is to ajax post to a controller action to update the partialView within the 'Success' block?

Comment: `if (data == "Success")` Yes on your success block

Comment: I got you, thanks for your help. I've selected the other as the correct answer for anyone who googles this problem, just because it's more comprehensive.